# XNA 3.1 Custom shader for certain sprites

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, sprite, shader

I'm trying for hours now to solve this problem..

So.. I want to use different shaders on every Sprite I draw on the screen.
I tried to make different RenderTarget2Ds but no success.

No matter how hard I try to make the Graphicsdevice.Clear() Transparent, it just won't work.
(I use xna 3.1)

So all my sprites blocking the other sprites because I can't make the background transparent :\

### Any idea ?

Code I use (it's a method):

```
 graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, r2d);
    graphicsDevice.Clear(ClearColor);
    spriteBatch.Begin();


    spriteBatch.Draw(
                tex,
               Dest,
               Source,
               moodcolor,
               this.RotationAngle,
               new Vector2(0, 0),
               Zoom,
               spriteEffect,
               this.Z_Index);

    spriteBatch.End();

    graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, null);
    graphicsDevice.Clear(ClearColor);

    for (int i = 0; i < efs.Count; i++)
    {
        efs[i].effect.CurrentTechnique = efs[i].effect.Techniques["Deferred"];

        foreach (EffectPass pass in efs[i].effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {

            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.None, SpriteSortMode.Immediate, SaveStateMode.None);
            efs[i].effect.Begin();
            pass.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(r2d.GetTexture(), Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
            pass.End();
            efs[i].effect.End();
        }
   }
```

Update!
You don't have to use RenderTarget2D!
It's important to keep AlphaBlend!
This is solution for anybody who came across the same problem!

Solution snippet:

```
foreach (EffectPass pass in efs[ObjShaders[i].ShaderID].effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
                    {

                        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend, SpriteSortMode.Immediate, SaveStateMode.None);
                        efs[ObjShaders[i].ShaderID].effect.Begin();
                        pass.Begin();

                        spriteBatch.Draw(
                         tex,
                        Dest,
                        Source,
                        moodcolor,
                        this.RotationAngle,
                        new Vector2(0, 0),
                        Zoom,
                        spriteEffect,
                        this.Z_Index);

                        spriteBatch.End();
                        pass.End();
                        efs[ObjShaders[i].ShaderID].effect.End();
                    }
```

Comment: Please post a picture of what you have and what you want - and some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your question again, perhaps all you need to do is

```
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
```

Now if your sprite textures have an alpha channel, they will be blended correctly.

Comment: It's still not solve my problem :(
My problem is that after I sent back the RenderTarget and Clear the screen, no matter which color I use it's still not transparent,so I can't use shaders on each object. :(

Comment: Why are you rendering each object into a separate rendertarget? Again - what is the end-result you wish to accomplish?

Comment: For example, I want to somehow manage to make a 2D shadowing shader. So for this I need to render shadow for each object. + Lighting effects to each object.

Comment: 2D shadowing? Do you mean shadowing from a sidescroller perspective or a pre-rendered drop shadow? Please post a picture of what you want so that people can help you do what you want in (possibly) easier ways. It is far better to describe your problem than to ask for an answer to something that you believe is the solution to your problem (see: thin metal ruler http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/03/53333.aspx).

Comment: Okay: picture: http://kepgep.hu/2012/06/20/main/halpme.jpg
I want to use different shaders at once,on objects.
I want to use them on objects,because I want to pass only that texture,not the whole screen as a texture (as on every 2d shader tutorial.)
So I want only that texture to be affected (and around the texture. example: the torchglowing.)

But no matter how hard I try, I can't achieve this,only full screen 2D shader with RenderTarget2D,which is not really helps me at all :\

Comment: To use a shader on ONE object - simply set the shaders parameters and use that shader to draw only that object to the framebuffer. Use blending to blend the object correctly with the background. Rinse and repeat for other objects.

Comment: How to do that? Everytime I try to set RenderTarget and change it back, the whole rendering have colored background not transparent :(

Comment: **You don't need to switch rendertargets to apply shaders on different targets**. I have been trying to tell you, what you want can be achieved by simply rendering each object with the correct blending function to the regular backbuffer without any intermediate clears (or swaps).